# Docker could not find or load main class. Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: src.com.company.Main.java

Tags: java, docker, intellij-idea

I am new to learning Docker, and followed a tutorial to make a small Hello World application to dockerize. I used Intellij template to generate a main method, which lies in the "com.company" package. All the method does is print out "Hello World!".

**The problem** is when I try to run the image from the terminal, it gives me this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class src.com.company.Main.java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: src.com.company.Main.java
```

I made a Docker file that looks like this:

```
FROM openjdk:11

RUN mkdir /app

COPY out/production/DockerTestApp/com/company/Main.class/ /app

WORKDIR /app

CMD java src/com/company/Main.java
```

For the "COPY" path, I just copied the Content Root path of the Main class in the "out" folder.

For the CMD path, I copied the Content Root path in the "src" folder.

This is the command I use to build the image(I give it a new TAG everytime):

```
docker build -t hello-world:3.0 .
```

I have tried writing the paths differently and creating the image again, but I just dont understand how Im supposed to write it.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: What happens if on your local device's command line you go to path `out/production/DockerTestApp/com/company/Main.class/` and run `java src/com/company/Main.java` (i.e. removing Docker from the equation)?

Comment: @JohnLBevan It works just as expected. Prints out "Hello World!" Edit: I apologize, I think i misunderstood your suggestion. I will run this in command prompt and check the results

Comment: @JohnLBevan I am not sure how to write it in the command prompt. How do I go to that path?

Comment: If you're running Linux then `cd /full/path/to/folder`; if  you're in Windows `pushd "c:\path\to\folder"`

Comment: @JohnLBevan Hey, thanks for your help! I think I know what the issue was. When I was creating the project in Intellij,, I just clicked the "Create project from template" checkbox, and it created the "com.company" folders. I tried to get rid of them, and eventually i got the path to work! So the problem was just that it wasnt reaching into the right place, because of the folders:)